# How can I detect a Paste event in a TextEditingController?

Tags: flutter

I have a TextEditingController which is for phone numbers. If text is pasted in it, I need to process and modify it, trimming whitespaces etc. But that should not happen if the user is typing in whitespaces. How can I differentiate between these two types of events, and call my function only when user pastes text into the field?

Currently my code looks like this and uses `onChanged`. I'm looking for something like onPaste:

```
String getCorrectedPhone(String phone) {
    phone = phone.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\s+"), "");
    return phone;
}

FormBuilderTextField(
    controller: _phoneController,
    name: "phone",
    onChanged: (String txt) {
        print('Phone field changed! Is now $txt');
        _phoneController.text = getCorrectedPhone(txt);
    },
),
```

[image]

Comment: if it was web, I would say use `LogicalKeySet`. But what about using postFrameCallback on `onChanged` , I'm not sure about you can give a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like declare a length with the phone number field and add a listener to the text editing controller or in oNchanged which checks if its length - the old length is >1. Then its pasted

```
int length = 0;
...

_phoneController.addListener((){
    if (abs(textEditingController.text.length - length)>1){
        // Do your thingy
    }
    length = _phoneController.length;
});
```

So there is another way, that is to ignore any touches on the text field using the IgnorePointer widget and then use Gesture Detector to implement custom long tap and short taps. For long taps, you'll have to create your own small pop up menu for copy cut paste and stuff. [Here](https://pastebin.com/jKcg71YW) is some sample code for the UI. As for the functioning, I would recommend using the https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard-class.html class of flutter. If you need any help in doing this let me know but it should be mostly straightforward

Comment: For detecting change in length, onChanged that I am using already works fine. What I'm looking for is specifically check if a paste event has occured like one can do for html

Comment: So just add the code instead of the listener in the onChanged and it will work. A past event can be detected if the length increases by more than 1

Comment: The question is specifically about detecting a clipboard paste, not about detecting whether the field has changed or not.

Comment: But in this case, if the field changes by more than 2 letters in one update, it means that the user has pasted something. Its not really the straight solution but a workaround. But it works in pretty much all scenarios I have tested so far. If the user was typing, it would change at most one letter an update. I have added another way which is a bit more in the straight way

Comment: Ah.. That may work in my case, as I expect pasting phone numbers which are at least more than 5 characters. For now, I changed the logic and added a paste button

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom selection controller to achieve paste content check.

You have to create the following class for the `MaterialTextSelectionControls` and `CupertinoTextSelectionControls` as well:

```dart
class CustomMaterialTextSelectionControl extends MaterialTextSelectionControls {
  ValueChanged<TextSelectionDelegate> onPaste;

  CustomMaterialTextSelectionControl({
    required this.onPaste,
  });

  @override
  Future<void> handlePaste(final TextSelectionDelegate delegate) {
    onPaste(delegate);
    return super.handlePaste(delegate);
  }
}
```

Now you have to use that `CustomMaterialTextSelectionControl` in your TextFormField like this:

```dart
        Container(
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: fullNameController,
            selectionControls: CustomMaterialTextSelectionControl(
                onPaste: (final TextSelectionDelegate delegate) async {
              final TextSelection selection = fullNameController.selection;
              final ClipboardData? data =
                  await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
              final text = data?.text ?? '';
              if (true) { //define your own condition
                //TODO: Handle Success Action
              } else {
                //TODO: Handle Failure Action
              }
            }),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: This is deprecated.